# Use value from locale file in thymeleaf expression

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is there any way to get `Thymeleaf` to interpret locale selectors in regular `Thymeleaf` expressions?

For example:

```
th:text="${userMsgRating.error ? #{rating_error} : #{rating_thanks}}"
```

Comment: Thats just how you get values from the locale file. (not a local file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using

```
th:text="${userMsgRating.error ? '__#{rating_error}__' : '__#{rating_thanks}__'}"
```

More information: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11353267)

Comment: I know that - that's why i answered.